# Exceptions in Swing from helper classes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, exception

I am working on a homework assignment to convert [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) Java Tutorial of the Knock Knock application to a Swing GUI application and use multithreading.

I have helper classes that are throwing Exceptions. These classes do not extend JFrame and I can't create new JOptionPane to show the exception. How would you show that Exception to the user?

For example: I have a class that loads the jokes from two text files (one for the clues and one for the answers). If the text files cannot be found in the location I expect, I am throwing a NullPointerException. Because this is a helper class it is not extending JFrame. How would I relate that message to the user? Do I just reference the javax.swing.JOptionPane showMessageDialog method like I have it in my code below or I can have another proxy class that catches exceptions and shows them?

```
    private final void getFilePath(ResponseFiles fileToGet) {
    String packagePath = "/com/knockknock/message";

    try {
    if (fileToGet == ResponseFiles.CLUES)
        file = new File(getClass().getResource(String.format("%s/clues.txt", packagePath)).getPath());
    else if (fileToGet == ResponseFiles.ANSWERS)
        file = new File(getClass().getResource(String.format("%s/answers.txt", packagePath)).getPath());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jokes Files Missing", "File Missing", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    }
```

What do you think?

Comment: The easiest way to show the exception is just to throw it all the way to the top and let the system print it.  You could also log the exception with the logger, at SEVERE it will normally print everything.

Comment: But if you're just trying to display messages, the easiest way is just to call the EDT and display a message with a JOptionPane static method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: See I did not thought of that. I was trying to extend the JFrame, just so I can use the JOptionPane, which I was sure it was not the way to go. I've edited my original post and I have my new method now.
Do you think it is worth having a proxy class that accepts Exceptions and prints out messages? Or that is unnecessary complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Swing components in business layer you can pass on the exceptions and handle it separately.

Have some custom Exception handler class where you can handle Runtime/Checked/Custom exceptions.

```
public class ExceptionHandler {
    public void handleException(Exception exp) {
        if (exp instanceof NullPointerException) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Jokes Files Missing", "File Missing",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if (exp instanceof IOException) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test", "Test",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        //Handle other exceptions
    }
}
```

Change your method like

```
private final void getFilePath(ResponseFiles fileToGet) {
    String packagePath = "/com/knockknock/message";

    if (fileToGet == ResponseFiles.CLUES)
        file = new File(getClass().getResource(
                String.format("%s/clues.txt", packagePath)).getPath());
    else if (fileToGet == ResponseFiles.ANSWERS)
        file = new File(getClass().getResource(
                String.format("%s/answers.txt", packagePath)).getPath());
}
```

In your business layer where GUI interaction is done you can handle exception like this. In your case since it is Runtime exception no explicit throwing is required.

```
    try {
        getFilePath(ResponseFiles.CLUES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new ExceptionHandler().handleException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. 
So I am guessing that if you have multiple classes that are throwing Exceptions, IOException for example, you would check the type of Exception and then check the glass that exception originated in. This will work in this small program, but just out of curiosity, is this how you would do it in a big industrial app?

Comment: There are several design patterns with respect to this regard. One of the most common design is write custom exceptions and passing the custom exceptions in all classes. Each custom exception will contain the message to display in screen, message to be logged in log file, stack trace of the exception.